# Efficient implementation of the transition matrix for page rank

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pagerank

I'm trying to implement PageRank. I'm reading the description here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/markov-chains-1.html

[image]

Everything is very clear to me, however I'm concerned about the construction of the matrix $P$. I find that constructing $P$ the naive way would be very expensive. For example: to implement step 1, one would need to check every row of $A$ and then check every element of that row to see if all elements are zero. For step 2 one would need to compute the number of ones for each row. I can imagine my code to have nasty slow loops. I was wondering if there are smart linear algebra techniques that could efficiently construct $P$. I will be using python numpy for my coding.

EDIT: one way I'm thinking now to solve this is by doing a summation element wise over the columns of $A$. By that I would have a column vector. Now I will go through each element of this vector to check which elements are zeros. Thus I can now know which rows has no 1s and I can multiply those rows with $1/N$.

Answer (score 2):

Your concern is correct. Since the number of web pages (vertices in the representing graph) is huge, it is impossible to actually generate such `A` and work on it.

The matrix calculation of page rank can be much more efficiently calculated using [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) implementations, since the matrix is very sparse. Most webpages are not actually connected to each other, so most entries in the matrix are 0.

The sparse matrix is built as follows:

- Build matrix A as described `A_ij = 1` if `(i,j)` is an edge, otherwise `A_ij = 0`
- Step 1 is usually not made, and instead we remove 'sinks' iteratively. This is done to prevent the matrix being dense, some alternatives are also linking 'sinks' back to the nodes that linked to them, or link a sink to itself.
- Divide each 1 in A as described in (2)

Let's denote the resulting matrix as `M`, and this is the resulting matrix we will work on, in order to get a column vector `p` (which is initialized with 1/n for each entry).

```
x = [1/n, 1/n, ... , 1/n]^T //a column vector
p = [1/n, 1/n, ... , 1/n]^T //a column vector with the initial ranks
M = genSparseMatrix() //as described above
do until p converge:
    p = (1-\alpha)* M*p + (\alpha) * x
return p
```

In the end, this yields `p`, the column vector that holds the page rank value for each node.

Comment: @AlexTwain See edit, I meant `M`,everywhere I wrote `A` in the pseudo code. Thanks.